# Apps Script: How to use token

Tags: email, google-apps-script, url, unsubscribe

I found [THIS pretty good explained script HIER](https://www.ravsam.in/blog/add-unsubscribe-link-in-emails-using-google-apps-script/) to add the unsubscribe option to my mail merger. It´s even recommended by Google. I´ve managed to install it, but I can´t figure out which value I should put in the last curly brace (so, `{{TOKEN}}`) in the HTML code below, because this is the first time ever that I work with tokens. Can somebody please help? I mean how would the value for `{{TOKEN}}` look like? Thanks :)

Here is the HTML code where I need assistance:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>We are testing our unsubscribe feature</h1>
    <a href="{{WEBAPP_URL}}?email={{EMAIL}}&unsubscribe_hash={{TOKEN}}"> Unsubscribe </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That link provides the hash. That's the token.

Comment: @TheMaster - In other words, it is enough to replace the values for `{{WEBAPP_URL}}` and `{{EMAIL}}` and leave `{{TOKEN}}` as it is?

Comment: You can, but it means anyone can unsubscribe. For eg, if you and I are subscribed to the service and I hate the service and I know your email as well. I can easily create the unsubscribe link for myself and for you too. If I'm a competing service, I can unsubscribe you and all others who are using my service from your service(because I will have their email upon registering to my service). Said otherwise, the token is like a password.

Comment: @TheMaster - Getting a little bit lost here, because the author of the original script is recommending to replace ALL values in curly braces (so, `{{WEBAPP_URL}}`, `{{EMAIL}}` and `{{TOKEN}}`). But you seem to differ (or I got you wrong). So, WHAT would you specifically replace and HOW? Thanks again for your help and huge contribution to our community. I really appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## WHAT?

- `WEBAPP_URL`

The url of you web application.

- `EMAIL`

The email of the recipient.

- `TOKEN`

Possibly a random string (hash) that is generated for each recipient (and may be also each email).

---

## HOW?

The replacement should be done when you are creating the emails.

The exact method depends on the tool (and such language) you use.

Commonly, you need to `replace` the values with the actual value stored in a variable

Here, I assume it is Google Apps Script.

```js
  var html =  HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index');
  var content = html.getContent().replace('{{EMAIL}}',  email);
  /* ... */
```

An alternative would be to use `scriplets`.

---

Reference:

- [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)
- [Pushing variables to templates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70149994/16125139)