# search function is not working in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am having one google sheet with student details about due amounts, around 2000 rows with four columns (**Student-Id, Name, Class, Amount Due**). If I submit the data, then the values are saving to the google sheet. But when I want to search the details with Student-Id, it is not working. I have tried in different ways and also googled, but couldn't find the correct code.  I am furnishing bot the codes (script & html file: **page.html**), could you help me in correcting the code.

file: page.html

```html
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
    <body>
      <h1> Data Form </h1>
      <div id ="hr">
         <label> Search </label>
         <input type = "text" id ="check">  <br>
         <buttin id = "get"  class="hor"> Check </button>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div id = "mr">
          <label> Student-ID: </label>
          <input type = "text" id ="sid"  <?= chk ?>  >   <br>
          <label> Student-Name: </label>
          <input type = "text" id ="name" <?= cname ?> > <br>
          <label> Class: </label>
          <input type = "text" id ="class" <?= cclass ?>  > <br>
          <label> Amount-Due: </label>
          <input type = "text" id ="due" <?= cdue ?>  > <br>
          <buttin id = "btn" class="hor" > Submit </button> 
      </div>
    
      <script>
         // saving data to google sheet through submit button
          document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", doStuff);
        function doStuff(){
             var userInfo = {};
                userInfo.id = document.getElementById("id").value;
                userInfo.name = document.getElementById("name").value;
                userInfo.class = document.getElementById("class").value;
                userInfo.due = document.getElementById("due").value;
             google.script.run.userClicked(userInfo);
        }
    
       // checking data from google sheet through check button
        document.getElementById("get").addEventListener("click", getStuff);
        var chk = document.getElementById("get").value                 
        google.script.run.userClicked(chk);
        }
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Google code

```js
    function doGet(){
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("page");
        }
    
      var url = "xxxx";
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
      var ws =ss.getSheetByName("Student");
      var rg = ws.getRange("A1:L");
      var data = rg.getValues();
     
    
       // for save data to google sheet
       function userClicked(userInfo){
           var sid = userInfo.sid;
           var name = userInfo.name;
           var class = userInfo.class;
           var due = userInfo.due;
       ws.appendRow([sid,name,class,due])
          }
       
       // check data from google sheet
       function userClicked(getInfo){
           for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ){  
               if(chk == data[i][0]){
                     cname = data[i][1];
                     cclass = data[i][2];
                 cdue = data[i][3];
                  }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have 3 questions for your question. 1. In your script, the scriptlets are used. But it seems that `page.html` is not used as the template. What do you want to do about this? 2. Can I ask you about the detail of your `google code`? 3. About `I want to search the details with Student-Id`, after the value was searched, what do you want to do?

Comment: This is template. When a student pays the amount, I will search the details from the Student-ID. Once the details are shown in the boxes for a certain student-Id, then I will edit the amount due and save to the google sheet. This just like populate of details.

Comment: Variables of `gs` and `html` are not 'linked'. [You should insert variables to template like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70149994/16125139) And you should pass variable to from `html` to `gs` functions with [`google.script.run`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run).